# To copy folder from a server to local drive using batch file

Tags: java, python-3.x, batch-file

I want to copy a folder containing jpeg from a server to my local drive as daily backup using bat file.

I know how to copy and paste using batch file in same computer, but how to access server. Please help

Comment: try googling ftp

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question is unfortunately off topic here as it is unclear what you are asking. Please include any code you have tried and give us more detail about your environment in order for one of us to assist you.

Comment: I'm interested in knowing how you can "paste using batch-file in same computer"

Comment: The term "help" implies that you made some efforts on your own. Please share a [mcve] of your own coding attempts and describe precisely what you want it to do and what it actually does. Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and learn [ask]!

Comment: I tried the code xcopy "source folder" "destination folder" /d. This is okay for coping file in same computer but my requirement is to copy from a server if anyone of you can help.

Answer (score -1):

For me the code is working fine (i tested it on my computer)

You can also use curl ou wget to do the same job. For example with wget:

```
powershell.exe -Command wget <file_url> -OutFile <file_name>
```

You can get wget for windows [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm).

Comment: I tried the code                                                                   xcopy "source folder" "destination folder" /d.                                                                                                    This is okay for coping file in same computer but my requirement is to copy from a server if anyone of you can help.